# Render Componente Modal en Index.jsx ReferenceError: setShowModal is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs

Estoy comenzando con react, tengo una aplicacion en la que cree el componente modal en ./components/Modal, lo importo al Navbar y cuando clico el boton de registrarme tengo el siguiente error `ReferenceError: setShowModal is not defined`  en escencia, no quiero tener el codigo del modal en el Navbar, solo cargarlo cuando me sea necesario y de esta forma hago la pagina mas liviana

les dejo el modal y mi Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Nav = () => {
    let Links =[
      {name:"HOME",link:"/"},
      {name:"COMUNITY",link:"/"},
      {name:"RESOURCES",link:"/"},
      {name:"CONTACT US",link:"/"},
    ];
    let [open,setOpen]=useState(false);
  return (
       
    <div className='shadow-md w-full fixed top-0 left-0'>
      <div className='md:flex items-center justify-between bg-white py-4 md:px-10 px-7'>
      <div className='font-bold text-2xl cursor-pointer flex items-center font-[Poppins] 
      text-gray-800'>
        <span className='text-3xl text-indigo-600 mr-1 pt-2'>
        <ion-icon name="logo-ionic"></ion-icon>
        </span>
        Proffesional Resources
      </div>
      
      <div onClick={()=>setOpen(!open)} className='text-3xl absolute right-8 top-6 cursor-pointer md:hidden'>
      <ion-icon name={open ? 'close':'menu'}></ion-icon>
      </div>

      <ul className={`md:flex md:items-center md:pb-0 pb-12 absolute md:static bg-white md:z-auto z-[-1] left-0 w-full md:w-auto md:pl-0 pl-9 transition-all duration-500 ease-in ${open ? 'top-20 ':'top-[-490px]'}`}>
        {
          Links.map((link)=>(
            <li key={link.name} className='md:ml-8 text-xl md:my-0 my-7'>
              <a href={link.link} className='text-gray-800 hover:text-gray-400 duration-500'>{link.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))
        }
       
      </ul>
      
      <ul>
      <button
        href="#" className="whitespace-nowrap text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
        >
              Sign up
       </button>
       
       

      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Cuando lo llamo desde el boton en la misma pagina Modal.jsx si funciona, el error es solo cuando lo llamo desde el Navbar.

Comment: `setShowModal` no existe, lo único que existe es `setOpen`. ¿Por que no intentas cambiar setShowModal por setOpen?

Comment: no no funciona ya lo inetente

Comment: En tu pregunta mencionas que creaste el componente modal `./components/Modal`. Sin embargo, yo no veo el código del Modal, y tampoco veo que este importado en el código que compartes.